# How to get open window instance from a third window

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have one window (in domain-1) from there I need to open a new window (in another domain say domain-2). Now in domain-2 I need to open a same window (parent of domain-1) but need to close the already opened window (which is parent).

*Is it possible?*

Flow is like:

domain1.window1 [1st] ----open in new window ---> domain2.window2 [2nd] ----- open in new window --> domain1.window1 [3rd],   but first instance needs to close.

One thing... is there any way by which one window can check whether it is already open; without the window object reference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Because of the [same origin policy](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/same-origin.html), you can't communicate between window 2 and window 1 and 3. So window 1 and 3 can't communicate. Unless you're using some session or cookies, but it's outside the scope of you question if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks..
could you please give some more idea (how to do that) on session or cookies?

Comment: For cookies there are some docs/examples around the web (for example : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html ). The idea would be to store a value to know when you go from window 1 to 2 and to check it in window 3). For the session, it will vary depending of your serverside language.